# Appium iOS automation using C#/Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, appium

I installed Appium and Xcode on my mac and trying to run code from Visual Studio on Windows VM, but to no success so far. Server's address and port in General Settings of the Appium on Mac are the same as in AppiumServers.cs class (127.0.0.1:4723). Please assist.
The error that I get, as to be expected, is below.

```
SetUp : OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:4723
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
```

Comment: I am using a sample available here: https://github.com/appium/appium-dotnet-driver/blob/master/samples/IosSimpleTest.cs

Answer (score 2):

I think I managed. The problem was with the IP address. 127.0.0.1 is local. I needed to change the IP address I was trying to connect to the IP of the Macbook Pro.